# Why form object doesn't load RecordSource attribute in VBA for Ms Access

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I need to read programmatically the **RecordSource attribute** of a form, to know what table or query is the form depending on.

After some research, it seems that the form object needs to be actually open in a window (or hidden, but open) so that certain attributes can be accessed. I've put together the following code snippet:

```
Application.DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", view:=acDesign, windowMode:=acWindowNormal     
Dim frm as Access.Form
Set frm = Forms("Form1").Form
Debug.print frm.Name            'works ok
Debug.print frm.RecordSource    'prints an empty string
Application.DoCmd.Close AcForm, "Form1"
```

I can see that the form is correctly open, but the RecordSource attribute is empty, eventhough the form is fed from a table.

What could be going on? I'm using .accdb Ms Access database files. And have compacted the database, just in case the db were corrupted, but the issue remains.

**Edit**: The form is very minimal, and I realize that actually has no RecordSource at all; it only has a subform which, since it is indeed fed with a table, does have a non-blank RecordSource.
So VBA was right returning a blank RecordSource for the parent form. The script posted was correct after all. Thanks for your inputs!!

Any hints or directions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Interesting. Note that if the form has a module, you can get the RecordSource without even opening the form at all: `Debug.Print Form_Form1.RecordSource`. **But:** the RecordSource will be evaluated when doing that, which may lead to all sorts of side effects (e.g. Access asking for parameters). For simple RecordSources, this can work well.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the *RecordSource* is assigned in code when the form is loaded, either as a table name or as SQL:

```
Me.RecordSource = "Select * From SomeTable Order By SomeField"
```

Answer (score 0):

In design view you can't get `RecordSource` programmatically. You can see from `Property` window. You have to open it as normal form, may be you want it to open as hidden. You can specify `WindowMode` to open form hiddenly by `DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acNormal, , , , acHidden`.  Try below codes.

```
Private Sub CmdTest_Click()
Dim frm As Access.Form

DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1", acNormal, , , , acHidden
Set frm = Forms("Form1")

    Debug.Print frm.Name
    Debug.Print frm.RecordSource

DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form1"
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not correct. Even a RecordSource in SQL will be listed.

Comment: @Gustav May be. I didn't try to get in `design view` yet.

Comment: I have tried both: view:= acNormal and view:=AcDesigns, and both seem to work correctly.

Comment: Did you tried like my answer just changing form name for your form.

Comment: Yes @Harun24HR, the code in your answer works just fine with the acNormal an acHidden parameters. The thing is finally my code also works, once I use the right form name (which had a subform, but no RecordSource). So it was my mistake here. Thanks a lot for casting light on the issue.